# table column break paragraph indendation

Tags: tables

I would like to `indent` the linebreaking in `table`. My expecting output is

[image]

My MWE IS:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{A summary of the default Rails directory structure.    \label{table:rails_directory_structure}}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lp{3.5in}@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{File/Directory} & \textbf{Purpose} \\
\midrule
\textbf{app/}  & Core application (app) code, including models, views,     controllers, and helpers \\
\textbf{app/assets} & Applications assets such as cascading style sheets     (CSS), JavaScript files, and images \\
\textbf{bin/} & Binary executable files \\
\textbf{config/}  & Application configuration \\
\textbf{db/}  & Database files \\
\textbf{doc/}  & Documentation for the application \\
\textbf{lib/}  & Library modules \\
\textbf{lib/assets} & Library assets such as cascading style sheets (CSS),     JavaScript files, and images \\
\textbf{log/}  & Application log files \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1` and put this and `\ttfamily` (which I found more suitable for this case over `\bfseries`) in the column specifiers themselves using `array` package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{A summary of the default Rails directory structure.    \label{table:rails_directory_structure}}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}>{\ttfamily}l
                        >{\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1}p{3.5in}@{}}
\toprule
File/Directory & \textbf{Purpose} \\
\midrule
app/  & Core application (app) code, including models, views,     controllers, and helpers \\
app/assets & Applications assets such as cascading style sheets     (CSS), JavaScript files, and images \\
bin/ & Binary executable files \\
config/  & Application configuration \\
db/  & Database files \\
doc/  & Documentation for the application \\
lib/  & Library modules \\
lib/assets & Library assets such as cascading style sheets (CSS),     JavaScript files, and images \\
log/  & Application log files \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]